# How to make Fortran pointers travel through C++

Tags: c++, fortran

I'm trying to insert a C++ layer between two Fortran subroutines. I also need to pass as argument a derived type that I don't want to declare in C++, since I don't neet to access to its data, and it is in my original program a complex type, using in turn a lot of other types.

I made a simple Fortran program:

```
module my_module

  implicit none

  type :: my_type
    real :: x
  end type my_type

end module my_module

subroutine fortran_subroutine(b)

  use my_module
  implicit none

  type(my_type), pointer, intent(in) :: b

  print *, b%x

end subroutine fortran_subroutine

program test

  use my_module
  implicit none

  abstract interface
      subroutine sub (b)
        import :: my_type
        type(my_type), pointer, intent(in) :: b
      end subroutine sub
  end interface

  type(my_type), pointer :: a

  procedure (sub), pointer :: f_ptr => null ()
  procedure (sub) :: fortran_subroutine

  allocate(a)
  a%x = 1.0

  f_ptr => fortran_subroutine
  call c_plus_plus_layer(f_ptr,a)

end program
```

And here is the C++ intermediate layer:

```
extern "C" 
{
  void c_plus_plus_layer_(void (*pointer_to_fortran_function)(void **), void ** x);
}

// Intermediate layer of C++ designed to launch a Fortran subroutine
void c_plus_plus_layer_(void (*pointer_to_fortran_function)(void **), void ** x)
{
  pointer_to_fortran_function(x);
}
```

However, I get an error when reaching the `print` instruction when compiling with the Intel compilers (v13), as I lost the data stored within my derived type somewhere in the C++ layer.

The gcc and gfortran compilers do not return anything.

May I ask for your help ?

Answer (score 5):

Fortran 2003 has a new way of interfacing with C. The module `iso_c_binding` declares a derived type `type(c_ptr)` that represents `void*` and the attribute `value` which lets you to pass the pointer by value. It also contains procedures `c_loc()` and `c_f_pointer()` for conversion of Fortran and C pointers.

For procedure pointers, similarly `type(c_funptr)`, and procedures `c_funloc()` and `c_f_procptr()` are available.

Study a lot of questions and answers here in tag [fortran-iso-c-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran-iso-c-binding)

Also, by using the `bind(C)` attribute, you get similar effects es `extern(C)` in C++ and you do not have to worry about name mangling and the trailing`_`. The `bind(C)` attribute is important to achieve the true `C` behavior of the Fortran procedure, e.g., the `value` attribute.

Note that if you use `bind(C)` the compiler will often warn you or even raise an error that Fortran `pointer` attribute cannot be used in such a procedure, because C wouldn't understand it.